# wp_list_table class is not safe to use

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I m using wp_list_table is not recommended to use or unsafe is there any alternative of this class ? or is there any safe work around ? creating new class with the plugin is not a best idea i guess so i want to know some recommendations for that .

Comment: Use custom class copy to override the original class if it changes in the future and supervise it when each WordPress update happens.

Answer (score 2):

While it's *technically* true that `WP_List_Class` is internal, in the real world it's used all the time by plugins, and I think at this point it's unlikely that Core will make any breaking changes to it.

Comment: how can we make a copy of this class to make it useable ?

Comment: I don't think you need to do that, you can just use the class that exists in WordPress.

Comment: hmm okay thanks